# How to combine GroupBox or DisclosureGroup with a List in a SwiftUI NavigationStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-layout

Ultimately, I am trying to replicate the layout used in Apple's Tips app:

[image: Screenshot of Apple's Tips app on iOS]

The app appears to have a NavigationStack that contains non-list items but that fit the overall list style. When I try to introduce a DisclosureGroup or GroupBox into the list, it has it's own padding for that item that I don't appear to be able to remove without removing it for all the lists breaking the layout achieved in the Tips app above.

If I introduce a ScrollView, then the List disappears and placing another item above the list makes only the List scrollable. This also stops the navigation bar from collapsing as you scroll.

Here's a simplified example of what I assumed would work:

```
NavigationStack {
    GroupBox(label: Text("My Label"), content: {
        Text("The content")
    })
    .padding()
    List {
        Section(header: Text("My First Section")) {
            Text("First list item")
            Text("Second list item")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
    .toolbarBackground(Color.blue)
}
```

In this example, the GroupBox appears tied to the NavigationStack title bar. If I give it a background colour, there's also a clear separation between the GroupBox and the List.

The Section headings are also non-standard but can be achieved with some simple modifiers but I am looking for a way to introduce non-list content into the scrollable view the List provides in SwiftUI.

I would happily place the GroupBox into a list if I could collapse the padding but that does not appear to work:

```
List {
    Section {
        GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
            Text("Content")
        })
        .listRowInsets(.none)
        .padding(0)
    }
}
```

I am not particularly bothered by the search bar, although this may be a useful requirement for the future. Right now I would just like to build a view that made use of the NavigationStack which sets a title for the view and when you scroll the entire page scrolls. The design language here fits my use case perfectly but I've struggled with the insertion of non-list elements and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `GroupBox` is inside the `List`, you can get rid of the extra padding by using explicit `EdgeInsets` instead of `.none`. Then to set a background color, use `.backgroundStyle`:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    List {
        Section {
            GroupBox("The Label") {
                Text("The Content")
            }
            .backgroundStyle(.yellow)
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

        Section(header: Text("My First Section")) {
            Text("First list item")
            Text("Second list item")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
    .toolbarBackground(Color.blue)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, you can just use a `VStack` and style it any way you like:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    List {
        Section {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                Text("The Label")
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("The Content")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.orange)

        Section(header: Text("My First Section")) {
            Text("First list item")
            Text("Second list item")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
    .toolbarBackground(Color.blue)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's it! I thought `.none` was an alias of some sort to achieve the same but clearly not!

Comment: Just adding a note here to say that with `DisclosureGroup` there is a noticeable white space at the top. Works fine with all other elements I've tried though.

Comment: @cchana I tried it with a simple `DisclosureGroup`, using `.listRowBackground` to set the background color. Don't notice any white space, instead it looks very like the other two variants already illustrated. Running on an iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.2.